# Get all adresses with less than 3000 transactions in a blocks interval

Tags: api, data

Given a block interval, I want to get every Solana address with less than 3,000 transactions.

For the moment, I check every block in the interval and write down the addresses. But I need 3 extra API requests (request 1000 transactions x 3) to check if it is greater or equal to 3,000.

I was expecting something like the ElasticSearch in the MultiversX blockchain, but I only found SubGraph which doesn't look like the solution. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue and the question, but when you get the addresses in the block, why don't you also keep a counter for each address? After you've received every block, you just need to filter for any address whose counter is less than 3000.

You'll mostly have to do this with RPC calls of `getBlock` at the moment, unless you want to ingest realtime data from a validator through Geyser https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins